# Remote control PC with xmpp

Tags: linux, debian, remote-control

I currently control my server via SSH from my phone.  There are times when the internet connection is sporadic or troublesome, or sometimes I have less urgent query and don't want to go the whole hog of launching SSH app.

Thanks to the suggestions made via comments I've chosen xmpp. From what I read I need an xmpp bot.

**How can I get an xmpp bot that supports OTR to run a script after receiving a message and then sending the response back via xmpp?**

I don't mind hosting the xmpp server or I can use a third party server. I have root access on server, it's running Debian.

I'd appreciate a brief example.

Comment: Are you running an email server on the server?

Comment: Not at the moment. It's more of a media server.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many ways of doing this, it would take all week to describe them all!

All you really need is something on the server that will monitor your inbox - or an alternative folder - read the appropriate messages - filter them for safety then parse the data and pass to a command processor - the command runs and returns some status data which is sent as a return email. Along the way, you need to update a flag on the emails so that you don't reprocess them.

I've written a number of systems like this in the past and they are useful and powerful.

If you are not into programming, then using something like IFTTT with notification service on the server would also work since IFTTT will act as the broker.

But really, you should look at some bespoke programming. All scripting languages such as Node.JS, Python and PHP have email processing libraries that can interact with email using IMAP and I've used both PHP and Node.JS.

If all that is too much for you, how about setting up a web site on the server that runs processes. I've done that too! For example, I have a Node.JS application that runs Windows PowerShell and other scripts remotely. (never got round to finishing the security on it though which is why it isn't published).

Thankfully, someone already did all that years ago. Installing [WebMin](http://www.webmin.com/) on the server gives a very fully featured web interface for remote management.

---

UPDATE: Well I told you there were lots of ways! Had you had an email server on the box with procmail, it would have been trivial.

However, one approach would be to install dropbox onto the server (you can use a new login if you don't want to compromise your main login). Then use IFTTT to listen to some other channel - email, SMS (in some countries) or one of many others. Use that to drop a text file into dropbox containing the instructions. On the server have a script that you run every few minutes using CRON (or create a filing system watch if you know how) that looks for new files, reads them and executes as needed. There are further details [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-issue-a-command-to-your-computer-with-a-text-message/), [here](http://www.epanorama.net/newepa/2014/07/02/ifttt-and-your-own-hardware/), [here](http://blog.joshhaas.com/2011/10/self-experimentation-using-ifttt-and-a-dash-of-python/) the first of which shows you the dropbox part, the others show some additional ideas on using IFTTT.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realise there could be so many potential answers so I'm going to try and narrown the field by updating question shortly. Strange I didn't fine anything via Google for the direct search terms.

Comment: Don't feel bad, the majority even of IT people wouldn't even think of it. It have slightly unusual experience in this area is all. If you want something quickly, webmin is the place to start.

Comment: I've added additional info. In effect not looking for bespoke approach unless it's trivial, would prefer something tried and tested .

Comment: I think the thing about webmin is I'd need a steady connection to make it work.

Comment: I misunderstood the intent of you're previous question. I don't have a mail program running at the moment but as I have root access I can  do.

Comment: Would like to see a proc mail example. Dropbox or cloud another storage service is certainly a valid approach.